# How to add string between processing strings

Tags: python, string

### condition 1

- I have strings 'hello world joe'
- I need to add `*` and `or` between them
- Expected out >> `'*hello* or *world* or *joe*'`

### condition 2

There is exclusion list is there for adding `*` ['or', 'and' 'not']

- If the input is `hello or world and joe`
- Expected out >>  `'*hello* or *world* and *joe*'`

If any space `' '` or `+` is there then it has to add string `or` if `and` and `not` is coming between the string then no need to add `*` between them

Code is below for condition1 how to incorporate condition2 also

```
value = 'hello world joe'
exp = ' or '.join([f'*{word.strip()}*' for word in value.split(' ')])
print(exp)
exclusion_list = ['or', 'and', 'not']
```

Comment: Hmm... "if `and` and `not` is coming between the string then no need to add `*` between them". So should the result of `'hello or world and joe'` be `'*hello* or *world* and *joe*'` or `'*hello* or *world* and joe'` or `'*hello* or world and joe'` or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# value = 'hello or world and joe'
>>> ' '.join(f'*{word}*' if word not in exclusion_list else word
                 for word in value.split())
'*hello* or *world* and *joe*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.sub` here with an alternation:

```py
inp = "hello or world and joe"
terms = ['or', 'and', 'not']
regex = r'(?!\b(?:' + '|'.join(terms) + r')\b)'
output = re.sub(regex + r'\b(\w+)\b', r'*\1*', inp)
print(output)  # *hello* or *world* and *joe*
```

Answer (score 0):

This can do the job:

```
value = 'hello or world and joe joe'
exclusion_list = ['or', 'and', 'not']

value = '*' + value.replace(' ','* or *') + '*'

for w in exclusion_list:
    value = value.replace(f'or *{w}* or', w)

print(value)
```

Output:

```
*hello* or *world* and *joe* or *joe*
```